# i create a vue.js project and found a problem

Tags: vue.js

I created a new project with `Vue Js` and I found a problem.

Code:

```
export default {
  name: 'welcome',
  mounted: function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: "thumbnails"
      });
  });
  }
}
```

Error on compiling:

> no such file or directory, open 'H:\task vue j\nemo\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js'

Browser error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: Can you maybe post the entire code? use 4 spaces in every line to make the ´code´ look like code.

Comment: Fixed code identation, wrote code instead of print images and added code and error blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery to node modules

> npm install jquery

Set jquery to $ and window in main.js

```
var $ = require('jquery')
window.jQuery = $
require('jquery.backstretch)
```

Source: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/use-jquery-properly/3638/5